# Is aqua aura quartz blue inside

Tags: minerals

How is aqua aura quartz made?

Is it a transparent non color quartz transformed into a blue quarts but only on the outside or on the inside too? What happens if I break an aqua aura crystal? Can the quartz be blue before the dying process begins? Do you have a before and after photo of a quartz turned into a aqua aura?

Comment: "Aqua aura quartz" is artificial.

Answer (score 0):

[Aqua aura quartz](https://geologyscience.com/gemstone/aqua-aura-quartz/) does not occur naturally. It is created by vapor deposition.

> clear quartz crystals are placed in a vacuum chamber, and a combination of pure gold and other trace metals are vaporized at high temperatures. The vaporized metal bonds to the surface of the quartz crystals, creating a thin, permanent layer of metallic iridescence. The specific metal used in this process, typically gold, is what gives Aqua Aura Quartz its distinct blue or aqua color.